# Как сделать бесшовную UV развертку шара (икосаэдра)?

Tags: opengl, текстура

Я написал алгоритм, который генерирует икосаэдр (20 граней, 12 вершин). Далее, применяя метод бисекции к каждому треугольнику нужное количество раз, я получаю сферу нужного "качества". Если данную модель скормить простому шейдеру, то можно увидеть качественный кругленький шарик. Проблемы пошли когда я назначил каждой вершине текстурные координаты и начал семплинг.

Про сферу я рассказал чтобы не было вопросов "зачем" и "почему", а проблема есть даже если оборачивать текстурой икосаэдр, так что для простоты вернусь к этой фигуре.

Текстура это прямоугольник, если этим прямоугольником оборачивать икосаэдр то будет некая условная линия стыка начала и конца прямоугольника текстуры. Линия этого стыка будет проходить через некоторые треугольники икосаэдра. Я не могу понять какие текстурные координаты задавать вершинам такого треугольника. Мы не можем "сместить" текстурные координаты этих верши в начало текстуры или в конец, 
так как на этих вершинах построены другие треугольники и с ними все в порядке.

Решений я вижу два.

1. Первое это изменить метод генерации шара так, чтоб у нас вершины на шаре образовывали дуги, к которым я смогу привязать линию стыка текстуры
2. Второе это треугольники на линии стыка разбить на другие треугольники, 
   чтоб вершины были четко на линии стыка, у них были одинаковые мировые координаты, но разные текстурные координаты.

Какой из методов лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть третий, гораздо более правильный метод:

Вам надо включить "повтор" текстур при выходе за диапазон UV 0..1.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); // Ось U
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT); // Ось V
```

Есть 4 основных типа повтора, вам нужен `GL_REPEAT` по оси U.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И соответственно сделать разветку по типу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не забудьте сделать разрыв в полигонах по разрыву на UV, чтобы не было "гармошки" на стыке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Именно в режиме повторения я и накладываю текстуру, не могу понять как сделать разрыв в полигонах, именно такую гармошку я и наблюдаю=)

Comment: Я так понимаю вы советуете сделать так: на картинке где вы привели пример развертки, если, к примеру, взять первую и последнюю вершину верхнего ряда, то у них совпадают мировые координаты, но u-координата у первой будет чуть больше нуля, а последняя чуть больше единицы?

Comment: @Alexei верно. Должны совпадать мировые координаты и нормали (и все остальное, кроме UV)